# Is there any possibility to obtain the displayed min and max values for X axis and Y axis on a chartjs graph?

Tags: reactjs, chartjs-2.6.0, react-chartjs, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I have a chartjs(wrapped by react-chartjs-2) line graph which is zoomable. The zoom functionality was enabled by using javascript library `chartjs-plugin-zoom` and passing the following configuration to `chartjs.ChartOptions`:

```
  pan: {
    enabled: true,
    mode: 'xy'
  },
  zoom: {
    enabled: true,
    mode: 'xy'
  }
```

On X axis I display the time and on Y axis some values related to my application. When I zoom or pan the chart the X axis **min** and **max** values change, here I need to obtain these values in order to perform a backend call(to update the chart) and also to synchronise it with another component in React.

Is there any possibility to obtain the new values for **min** and **max** upon a zoom or pan? I tried to look for a callback function which would provide this but found none so far.

Comment: Did you find anything?